# Property initializers run before 'self' is available

Tags: swift, class, properties, init, lazy-initialization

Seems like I'm having a problem with something that shouldn't be the case... But I would like to ask for some help.

There are some explanations here on the Stack I don't get.

Having two simple classes where one refers to another, as per below:

```
class User {
  lazy var name: String = ""
  lazy var age: Int = 0

  init (name: String, age: Int) {
      self.name = name
      self.age = age
  }
}

class MyOwn {
  let myUser: User = User(name: "John", age: 100)
  var life = myUser.age 
  //Cannot use instance member 'myUser' within property initializer
  //property initializers run before 'self' is available
}
```

I get the commented compile error. May someone please tell me what should I do to solve the case?

Comment: Put the code in a method. You cannot initialize properties which depend on each other on the top level of the class. Or use a computed property. Btw: the `lazy` attributes in the `User` class are useless.

Comment: @vadian, thanks for your help.

Comment: that's a v surprising limitation in `swift` : any ideas why it is like this?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

As correctly pointed out by **vadian** you should create an `init` in such scenarios:

```
class MyOwn {
    let myUser: User
    var life: Int

    init() {
        self.myUser = User(name: "John", age: 100)
        self.life = myUser.age 
    }
}
```

You can't provide a default value for a stored property that *depends* on another instance property.

Comment: this one surely answers to my problems. Thank you!

Comment: Why does our lovely IDE not propose this?

Answer (score 29):

You should declare life like this:

```
lazy var life:Int = {
    return self.myUser.age
}()
```

Because you are trying to initialise one property(variable) with another during initialisation process. At this time variables are not available yet.

Comment: Should work fine, but isn't using `lazy` for that an overkill? ;-)

Comment: @PauloMattos The code architecture presented in your answer is more acceptable, at least for me. But I can not say why a person needed the architecture that he is trying to implement. I just showed him how to do it without compilation errors and explained what was his mistake

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is turning the variable into a computed property

```
// Previous declaration
var temperatureString = String(format:"%.1f", temperature) // "Cannot use instance member 'temperature' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available" 

// Computed Property
var temperatureString : String { 
   return String(format:"%.1f", temperature)
}
```