# swift property initializers run before 'self' is available

Tags: swift, function, constructor, init

I have the following 2 classes Item & Items:

```
class Item{
    var name: String

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Items{
    init(item: Item?) {
        self.item = item
    }
    var item: Item?
}
```

Then I try to do:

```
class MockData{        
    let item1 = Item(name: "XXX")
    let items : Items = Items(item: item1)
}
```

I get error at the second var:
Cannot use instance member 'item1' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Why is that ?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, where exactly are you doing it? Is it inside a view controller or something similar? Does declaring `item1` as `lazy var` resolve the issue?

Comment: @AhmadF I guess it's because you're using a playground. If you put both the variables inside a class then you'll run into the issue mentioned...

Comment: @Honey correct, that's why the question should contain the code that reproduces the issue :)

Comment: I have edited my question.. as you can notice. I am simply calling the constructor of Items from within different class. why its not working ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a good explanation already here: [Property initializers run before 'self' is available](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43550813/793607)

But you can't initialize properties that depend on each other at the top level of a class or struct.

```
struct dummy {
    let item1: Item
    let items1 : Items = Items(item: item1)

    init(name: String) {
        item1 = Item(name: name)
        items1 = Items(item: item1)
    }

}
```

Comment: That `lazy var` can be `let`, as long as you don't use the property initializer. (I think maybe you're trying to combine two examples into one?)

Comment: Thanks @Jessy I got sloppy after false starting in a different (and bad) solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot execute code on the top level of a class which refers to `self`.

What you can do is to create `Item` in the same line

```
class MockData {
    let items = Items(item: Item(name: "XXX"))
}
```