# SwiftUI "Cannot use instance member 'numberOfDevice' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available" error

Tags: swiftui

The bolded line (ie var text: String...) gives a "Cannot use instance member 'numberOfDevice' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available" error. Do I need an init? If so where? Is there a different solution?

```
struct PairView: View {
    var theClass = BluetoothManager()   
    init() {theClass.viewDidLoad()}     

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<BluetoothManager.peripheralArray.count) {   number in  //iterates thru 0 to array's count
            ConnectionView(numberOfDevice: number)      // create a ConnectionView for each number
        }
     }
  }
}

//-------

struct ConnectionView: View {
    
    var numberOfDevice: Int
    **var text: String = (BluetoothManager.peripheralArray[numberOfDevice]?.name)!**  
    // 'name' is a String property of the B.M. class's array's 'numberOfDevice index.'

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0).fill(Color.blue)
            Text(text).foregroundColor(Color.black)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550813/property-initializers-run-before-self-is-available This should help

Comment: Can you give more information about your BluetoothManager and the peripheralArray, what object is stored in there? Can that object be made identifiable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use read-only computed property with short-hand.

```
var text: String { 
       return (BluetoothManager.peripheralArray[numberOfDevice]?.name)!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error you encountered means you can't use the `numberOfDevice` variable to instantiate another variable. However, you can use the `number` you pass to your `init` method.

Try the following:

```
struct ConnectionView: View {
    
    var numberOfDevice: Int
    var text: String
    
    init(numberOfDevice: Int) {
        self.numberOfDevice = numberOfDevice
        self.text = (BluetoothManager.peripheralArray[numberOfDevice]?.name)!
    }
    ...
}
```

Note: I don't recommend force-unwrapping (`!`). If possible try to provide a default value.

Also, `BluetoothManager` looks like a *type* and not like an *instance* of a class. Make sure you access the `peripheralArray` property on the valid object and not on the `BluetoothManager` type.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, It worked as well (@IFTTT's also solved it).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lazy` keyword for that:

```
lazy var text: String = (BluetoothManager.peripheralArray[numberOfDevice]?.name)!
```

---

#### What is lazy?

`lazy` means that it will postpone initialization until someone calls the variable and it will not possible if `self` is not initialized. So you will be sure `self` is ready before accessing that value.

#### Why?

When you call `numberOfDevice`, you are actually calling `self.numberOfDevice`, but swift is smart enough to let you not explicitly write `self` keyword.

The issue here is that `self` is not initialized yet when you are assigning a value to a variable.

So you need to make sure the variable is initialized **BEFORE** accessing `self`.

Comment: I had tried using lazy as recommended in many similar questions, but a lot of other errors popped up around the code, which is mainly why I asked the question. Thank you, though!