# swiftui @State value depends on @ObservedObject ViewModel init error

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have simple `viewModel`:

```swift
final class EmployeeListViewModel: ObservableObject {
 @Published var list = [Employee]()
 init() {
  // some request
  self.list = [Employee, Employee]
 }
}
```

And have a `view`:

```swift
struct EmployeeView: View {
 @ObservedObject var viewModel = EmployeeListViewModel()
 @State private var showContents: [Bool] = Array(repeating: false, count: viewModel.list.count)// <- error throws here
 var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { fullView in
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 40) {
                  ForEach(self.viewModel.list) { employee in
                     Text(employee.firstName).foregroundColor(.black)
                  }
                }
            }
        }
 }
}
```

Error text:

> Cannot use instance member 'viewModel' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

I tried change it with `init`:

```swift
struct EmployeeView: View {
 @ObservedObject var viewModel = EmployeeListViewModel()
 @State private var showContents: [Bool]

 init() {
        _showContents = State(initialValue: Array(repeating: false, count: viewModel.list.count)) // <- error
    }

 var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { fullView in
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 40) {
                  ForEach(self.viewModel.list) { employee in
                     Text(employee.firstName).foregroundColor(.black)
                  }
                }
            }
        }
 }
}
```

But it also throws error:

> 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized

this throws on I call `viewModel` on `init()`

How to solve it? @State i use for card view. There I simplified views for easy understand.

Comment: Use an `init` or declare the variable as `lazy`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize properties that depend on each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854300/how-to-initialize-properties-that-depend-on-each-other). Or this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550813/property-initializers-run-before-self-is-available

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I updated question. `init` doesnt resolve. Or I used it with mistake

Comment: @JoakimDanielson tried move code on `init` to `onAppear` it throws `Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is possible solution

```
struct EmployeeView: View {
 @ObservedObject var viewModel: EmployeeListViewModel     // << declare
 @State private var showContents: [Bool]                  // << declare

 init() {
       let vm = EmployeeListViewModel()   // create here !!

       // initialize both below
       self.viewModel = vm                     
       self._showContents = State(initialValue: Array(repeating: false, 
              count: vm.list.count))
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First initialise the state variable to an empty array

```
@State private var showContents: [Bool] = []
```

then set it in the `init`

```
init() {
    showContents = Array(repeating: false, count: viewModel.list.count)
 }
```

You shouldn't initialise the view model property in the view but rather use dependency injection

```
init(viewModel: EmployeeListViewModel) {
    self.viewModel = viewModel
    showContents = Array(repeating: false, count: viewModel.list.count)
}
```