# what is difference of self in lazy var and var(let) block

Tags: ios, swift

when I use `let` `UISwitch` replace `lazy var` `UISwitch` in `UITableViewCell` like this:

```
let trigger: UISwitch = {
    let sw = UISwitch()
    sw.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onTriggerChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    return sw
}()
```

I found the function `onTriggerChanged` never called, so I do some test, here is my test code:

```
class TestCell: UITableViewCell {

    lazy var trigger: UISwitch = {
        let sw = UISwitch()
        print("trigger \(self)")
        sw.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onTriggerChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
        return sw
    }()
    
    var trigger2: UISwitch = {
        let sw = UISwitch()
        print("trigger2 \(self)")
        sw.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onTriggerChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
        return sw
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        let trigger3: UISwitch = {
            let sw = UISwitch()
            print("trigger3 \(self)")
            sw.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onTriggerChanged(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
            return sw
        }()

        contentView.addSubview(trigger)
        contentView.addSubview(trigger2)
        contentView.addSubview(trigger3)
    }


}
```

print message is:

```
trigger <TestCell: 0x......>

trigger2 (Function)

trigger3 <TestCell: 0x......>
```

and trigger2 valueChanged event not called.

so what difference of self in trigger/trigger2/trigger3

Comment: I get a warning that says "String interpolation produces a debug description for a function value; did you mean to make this explicit?" in trigger2, which makes it very clear what `self` means there. Do you not get one?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you're aware, [`self` (in the usual sense) is not available in property initialisers of non-lazy properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550813/property-initializers-run-before-self-is-available), which is why you use `lazy` as a workaround.

The `self` that you are printing in trigger2 can't refer to the `self` instance. It actually refers to an instance method called [`self`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418954-self?language=objc), declared in `NSObject`, which is inherited by `TestCell`.

This is actually an instance method. In Swift, you are allowed to refer to instance methods without having an instance (remember that you don't have access to the *actual* `self` instance here). It's just that their type becomes `(T) -> F`, where `T` is the type in which the instance method is declared, and `F` is the function type for the method. Essentially, they become static methods that take an instance as parameter, and give you back the original instance method.

For example, the `self` method, when referenced without an instance, would have the type:

```
(TestCell) -> (() -> TestCell)
```

You can see that is indeed what it is by printing out `type(of: self)`.

Clearly, adding the `self` *method* as the target doesn't work. It can't respond to the selector `onTriggerChangedWithSender`.

For trigger1 and trigger3, the `self` instance *is* available, and `self` mean the usual thing - the current instance.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy var is computed when the variable is required somewhere and only runs the initializing code once while non lazy var and let compute the value when the variable is initialized. and where is the onTriggerChanged function.