# Why UITapGestureRecognizer does not work if we make it become the member variable of a class?

Tags: ios, swift

I was wondering, why `UITapGestureRecognizer` doesn't work, if we make it become the member variable of a class?

### Not working. hideKeyboard is not called when tapped

```
class TabInfoSettingsCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    private let hideKeyboardTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hideKeyboard))

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.addGestureRecognizer(hideKeyboardTapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    @objc private func hideKeyboard() {
        print("hide keyboard")
    }
```

---

### Working

```
class TabInfoSettingsCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let hideKeyboardTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hideKeyboard))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(hideKeyboardTapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    @objc private func hideKeyboard() {
        print("hide keyboard")
    }
```

---

Do you have idea what is the reason behind, on why `UITapGestureRecognizer` does not work if we make it become the member variable of a class?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68205981/what-is-difference-of-self-in-lazy-var-and-varlet-block/68206356#68206356). `self` doesn't mean what you think it does when in a variable initialiser.

Comment: https://www.biteinteractive.com/rant-swift-cocoa-target-action/

Answer (score 1):

Property initializers are run before the class initializer. This means that `self` (the instance of the class in this case) is not available before class init (at the time of property initialization).

If you make it a `lazy var` instead, it will be executed later in the lifecycle after init has been run and it will work as expected.