# swift tap gesture handler not invoked

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have the following custom view implementation :

```
import UIKit

class ProfileTableHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    private var statusText : String = ""
            
    private let fullNameLabel: UILabel = {
        let view = UILabel()
        view.text = "Hipster Pinguin"
        view.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .bold)
        view.textColor = .black
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
        
    private let avatarImage: UIImageView = {
        let view = UIImageView()
        view.clipsToBounds = true
        view.layer.borderWidth = 3
        view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        view.image = UIImage(named: "avatar")
        view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 100/2
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

//        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target : self, action : #selector(avatarImagePressHandler))
//        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
//        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        return view
    }()
    
        
    let statusLabel: UILabel = {
        let view = UILabel()
        view.text = "Waiting for something"
        view.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: .regular)
        view.textColor = .gray
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
        
    let statusTextField: UITextField = {
        let view = TextFieldWithPadding()
        view.placeholder = "add smth to show as status"
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        view.layer.borderWidth = 1
        view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .regular)
        view.textColor = .black
        view.backgroundColor = .white.withAlphaComponent(0)
        view.addTarget(self, action: #selector(statusTextChanged), for : .editingChanged)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
        
    let setStatusButton: UIButton = {
        let view = UIButton()
        view.setTitle("Show status", for: .normal)
        view.setTitleColor(.white, for : .normal)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "myColor")
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 14
        view.layer.shadowRadius = 4
        view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 4, height: 4)
        view.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()
            
    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupViews()
    }
        
    @objc func avatarImagePressHandler()
    {
        print("avatar pressed")
    }
    
    @objc func buttonPressed()
    {
        statusLabel.text = statusText
    }
    
    @objc func statusTextChanged(_ textField: UITextField)
    {
        statusText = textField.text ?? ""
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("should not be called")
    }
    
    
    private func setupViews()
    {
        contentView.addSubview(avatarImage)
        contentView.addSubview(fullNameLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(statusLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(statusTextField)
        contentView.addSubview(setStatusButton)
                
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target : self, action : #selector(avatarImagePressHandler))
        avatarImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        avatarImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        let constraints = [
            avatarImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 16),
            avatarImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            avatarImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            avatarImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            
            fullNameLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 27),
            fullNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: avatarImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 16),
            fullNameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
         
            statusLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fullNameLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            statusLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fullNameLabel.leadingAnchor),
            statusLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fullNameLabel.trailingAnchor),

            statusTextField.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: statusLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            statusTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            statusTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: statusLabel.leadingAnchor),
            statusTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: statusLabel.trailingAnchor),

            setStatusButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: avatarImage.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
            setStatusButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: avatarImage.leadingAnchor),
            setStatusButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            setStatusButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
        ]
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }

}
```

If I try to setup a tap gesture recognizer inside lambda I see no print inside the console, but if I configure it inside `setupViews` everything is fine. Why does it work this way? What am I missing?

Comment: Use ```lazy var  avatarImage: UIImageView ```

Comment: @RajaKishan why should I do it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68206356/14733292

Comment: @RajaKishan ok, and why does the snippet for let setStatusButton: UIButton = { work as expected?

Comment: for the button, you are using addTarget. might have different mechanisms. By adding a target you are assigning an action. But the gesture is different things.

Comment: Although` UIGesureRecogniser` will accept `nil` for the target, the documentation says that it is not a valid value. A Button is a subclass of `UIControl` which has a different behaviour. If the target is `nil` then it walks up the responder chain to find the first object that implements the selector.

Comment: @Abizern great explanation ! thanks a lot