# why can't my SwiftUI struct be initialised outside the View?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, struct

I couldn't get my the below struct to initialise until I moved it into the body of the View. Can someone explain that to me please? Thanks!

This didn't work:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var sampleText = "This is sample text"
    var booksArray = ["Book 1", "Book 2", "Book 3"]
    let aBook = Book(passage: sampleText, books: booksArray)
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false, content: {
            VStack {
                Text(aBook.passage)
                    .frame(width: 350, height: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                    .kerning(1)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

But this did work:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var sampleText = "This is sample text"
    var booksArray = ["Book 1", "Book 2", "Book 3"]
    
    var body: some View {
        let aBook = Book(passage: sampleText, books: booksArray)
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false, content: {
            VStack {
                Text(aBook.passage)
                    .frame(width: 350, height: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                    .kerning(1)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you got? It should sufficiently explain what the problem is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Property initializers run before 'self' is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550813/property-initializers-run-before-self-is-available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you got from this code reads:

> cannot use instance member 'sampleText' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

which in plain English means that when `aBook` is being assigned, `self`, which is the `ContentView` is not yet available, so you cannot use `sampleText` and `booksArray` to initialize `aBook` (because it requires all the properties to be initialized - to hold a value).

You might think, ok then I will use `lazy` to initialize `aBook`, which means that the assignment of the property will happen after `ContentView` has finished the initialization - at first access.

`lazy var aBook = Book(passage: sampleText, books: booksArray)`

but then a new error appears:

> Text(aBook.passage) <= cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: 'self' is immutable

wait, what? But I'm not trying to mutate it you might say.

The reality though is that you *do* mutate `ContentView` by accessing `aBook`. Let's illustrate this:

1. `sampleText` is assigned a value
2. `booksArray` is assigned a value
3. `aBook` is not assigned since is `lazy`. Waits for access in order to be assigned a value.
4. `ContentView` is initalized
5. You access `aBook` in the body
6. `aBook` *tries* to assign a value, but because `ContentView` is a struct (value type - immutable) it needs to make a *copy* of the whole thing. Which is why you get the error

So, long story short you got a few options:

1. `let aBook = Book(passage: sampleText, books: booksArray)` in the body (as you already mention)
2. A computed property:

   `var aBook: Book { Book(passage: sampleText, books: booksArray) }`

or a custom initializer:

```
init(sampleText: String, booksArray: [String]) {
    self.sampleText = sampleText
    self.booksArray = booksArray
    self.aBook      = Book(passage: sampleText, books: booksArray)
}
```

or even:

```
let sampleText = "This is sample text"
let booksArray = ["Book 1", "Book 2", "Book 3"]
let aBook: Book

init() {
    self.aBook = Book(passage: sampleText, books: booksArray)
}
```

I hope that this makes sense.