# "Cannot use instance member '' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

Tags: swift

I think it's pretty common problem, but I haven't found the solution. Here is the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var monthLabel: UILabel!
    
    let date = Date()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.current
    let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
    //let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
    //let day = calendar.component(.weekday, from: date)
    //let dateDay = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // some code
    }

    @objc func addStory(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("Button tapped")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "addStory", sender: self)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "addStory"{
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ResultsViewController
           // destinationVC.currentDayKey =
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to build it I get the "Cannot use instance member 'calendar' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available" and "Cannot use instance member 'date' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

But if I initialise month, day and dateDay in viewDidLoad everything works. How to declare them on the top?

I've tried to find some solutions with same error, but nothing helped

Comment: Your error is likely on the `let month = ...` line, as this uses another variable (`calendar`) before the class is initialized. I would take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43550813/20384561).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize properties that depend on each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854300/how-to-initialize-properties-that-depend-on-each-other)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But if I initialise month, day and dateDay in viewDidLoad everything works. How to declare them on the top?

The error is specifically telling you that you can't initialize a property in terms of another property. Instead, you'll need to set the property *after* the property initializers have run. The way to do that is to provide an initializer for the class.

Here's a simpler version of your problem code:

```
class Foo {
    var date = Date()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.current
    var month: calendar.component(.month, from:date)
}
```

That last line causes an error because it uses `date`, which is also a property. Adding an `init` method that sets `month` solves the problem:

```
class Foo {
    var date = Date()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.current
    var month: Int
    
    init() {
        month = calendar.component(.month, from:date)
    }
}
```

Notice that if you initialize a property in `init`, you have to specify the type explicitly — the compiler can't infer the type if there's no value to infer it from.

Incidentally, it seems likely that you might always want `month` and `date` to agree, so it might make more sense to make `month` a computed property, in which case you don't need the `init`, and you might not need a separate `calendar` property either. Note also that in Swift you can use `Calendar` instead of `NSCalendar`:

```
class Foo {
    var date = Date()
    var month: Int {
        Calendar.current.component(.month, from: date)
    }
}
```