# How to load JSON dynamically in reusable SwiftUI Struct?

Tags: json, swift, swiftui, struct

In my SwiftUI project, I want to reuse a Struct. The Struct is called "GeneralView". In that Struct I want to display text from a json file and the code for this looks like this:

```
Text(QuestionsData[currentQuestionIndex].question)
```

At the top of my Struct, I have defined the json file as follows:

```
var QuestionsData: [Questions] = load("question.json")
```

and in a separate file I have written the code to read the json file:

```
import Foundation

struct Questions: Hashable, Codable {
    var id: Int
    var question: String
    var fav: Bool
    var category: String
}

//and so on...
```

When I reuse the Struct, I want to be able to change which file to read data from, such as this:

```
GeneralView(fileName: "date.json")
```

But it doesn't work. If I write this code at the top of the GeneralView-Struct:

```
var fileName: String

var QuestionsData: [Questions] = load(filename)
```

I get an error message stating that "Cannot use instance member 'fileName' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

How can I write the code so that I can choose which file the GeneralView should read data from when I call the GeneralView Struct?

I have read another question here at Stack overflow ([Property initializers run before 'self' is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550813/property-initializers-run-before-self-is-available)) that I should use init(), but I tried this and it did not work:

```
var fileName: String
var questionsData: [Questions]

init(fileName: String) {
    self.fileName = fileName
    self.questionsData = load(fileName)
}
```

Can someone pleas help?