Filter elements of a String variable contained in an Identifiable
I'm coding a Swift application for macOS.
I'm a beginner in Swift so my problem might seem stupid to you, I apologize for that...
I have a type containing the following two String variables:
struct ShortcutInfo: Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
}

The variable I use the most is "name", containing a list of texts.
I tried to filter the list with a TextField. The filtered list should appear in the Picker.
@State var filteredShortcuts = ShortcutInfo(id: "", name: "").name.filter($0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))

// body
TextField("", text: $searchText)
                        
Picker("", selection: $selection) {
    ForEach(filteredShortcuts) { item in
        Text(item)
    }
}

But I get the error "Cannot use instance member 'searchText' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available".
What is wrong in my code?
Full code:
@State var shortcuts = [ShortcutInfo]()
@State var selection = ""
@State var searchText: String = ""
@State var filteredShortcuts = ShortcutInfo(id: "", name: "").name.filter($0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))

// body
TextField("", text: $searchText)
                        
Picker("", selection: $action1a) {
    ForEach(filteredShortcuts) { item in
        Text(item)
    }
}
.task {
     let shortcuts = (try? await loadShortcutNames()) ?? []
     self.shortcuts = shortcuts
     selection = shortcuts.first?.id ?? ""
}
//

func loadShortcutNames() async throws -> [ShortcutInfo] {
    let process = Process()
    process.executableURL = URL(filePath: "/usr/bin/shortcuts")

    process.arguments = ["list", "--show-identifiers"]
    let pipe = Pipe()
    process.standardOutput = pipe
    return try await withTaskCancellationHandler {
        try process.run()
        return try await pipe.fileHandleForReading.bytes.lines.compactMap { line in
            guard let (_, name, id) = line.wholeMatch(of: /(.*) \(([A-Z0-9-]*)\)/)?.output else {
                return nil
            }
            return ShortcutInfo(id: String(id), name: String(name))
        }
        .reduce(into: []) { $0.append($1) }
    } onCancel: {
        process.terminate()
    }
}

struct ShortcutInfo: Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
}

extension Binding where Value == Int {
    var toString: Binding<String> {
        Binding<String>(
            get: {
                "\(wrappedValue)"
            },
            set: {
                wrappedValue = Int($0) ?? 0
            }
        )
    }  
}

In addition, I am not sure of the validity of my code regarding the display of the list in the Picker.
Thanks in advance.

Just a clarification since you are a beginner, you don’t have an Identifiable you have a (custom) type conforming to the Identifiable protocol. Or shorter: you have a type.

Does this answer your question? Property initializers run before 'self' is available

The error you get is because you cannot declare @State var filteredShortcuts = ShortcutInfo(id: "", name: "").name.filter($0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())) and use searchText in it.
Declare @State var filteredShortcuts = ShortcutInfo(id: "", name: "") and in your own init(...) or .onAppear{...}
do the filter using the searchText, after the property initializer has been done. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43550813/property-initializers-run-before-self-is-available

You cannot filter the text on the top level, you have to filter the text for example in the onChange modifier
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var shortcuts = [ShortcutInfo]()
    @State private var selection = "None"
    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    @State private var filteredShortcuts = [ShortcutInfo]()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("", text: $searchText)
            
            Picker("", selection: $selection) {
                Text("Nothing selected").tag("None")
                ForEach(filteredShortcuts) { Text($0.name) }                   
            }
            .onChange(of: searchText) { _, newValue in
                filteredShortcuts = shortcuts.filter{$0.name.localizedStandardContains(searchText)}
                selection = filteredShortcuts.first?.id ?? "None"
            }
        }
        .task {
            self.shortcuts = (try? await loadShortcutNames()) ?? []
            selection = "None"
        }
    }
    
    func loadShortcutNames() async throws -> [ShortcutInfo] {
        let process = Process()
        process.executableURL = URL(filePath: "/usr/bin/shortcuts")
        
        process.arguments = ["list", "--show-identifiers"]
        let pipe = Pipe()
        process.standardOutput = pipe
        return try await withTaskCancellationHandler {
            try process.run()
            return try await pipe.fileHandleForReading.bytes.lines.compactMap { line in
                guard let (_, name, id) = line.wholeMatch(of: /(.*) \(([A-Z0-9-]*)\)/)?.output else {
                    return nil
                }
                return ShortcutInfo(id: String(id), name: String(name))
            }
            .reduce(into: []) { $0.append($1) }
        } onCancel: {
            process.terminate()
        }
    }
}


But the list of "name"s (ShortcutInfo) is always modified: a function loads the names of all the Siri shortcuts from apps files. So, I can't enumerate the items manually in a @State...

Please edit the question and add the relevant code where the unfiltered list comes from.

Please see the edit. It's pretty close to my primary answer.
